# UITableViewDataSource methods not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am updating my `UITableView` with the following code:

```
int index = [self.guests indexOfObject:_guests];

[[self tableView] beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[[self tableView] endUpdates];
```

But after calling `[[self tableView] endUpdates]`, its not calling its datasource methods. In case of adding row, it calls its datasource methods. I think in case of deletion it does not need to ask anything to its datasource, but in case of adding a row it needs to ask its datasource about pretty much everything about the new row added like cellForRow, height etc etc. I just want to make sure that is it right if `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` is not calling any of its datasource methods??

Comment: Do you have all the cells visible at the same time ?

Comment: you'll need to call `[tableView reloadData];` after endUpdates

Comment: without reloadata , tableView will not call its delegate methods?@AhmedZ.

Comment: Yes all the cells are visible, i just want to know does tableview calls its datasource methods if we delete a row from tableview using the method written in my question. If we add a row, it do calls @A-Live

Comment: check this out [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9)

Comment: its written in he link "At the conclusion of a block—that is, after endUpdates returns—the table view queries its data source and delegate as usual for row and section data"@Ishank

Comment: @iVishal reloadData will call the methods of tableView hence the cell updated will be shown

Comment: @AhmedZ. I want to know , why delegates methods are not geting called after endUpdates?

Comment: As you have all the cells visible this behavior seems to be expected. However nobody can say that datasource methods are not going to be called in this situation, if apple engineers decided to do it for any fancy reason the methods'd be called and if they saw an opportunity for optimization by skipping unnecessary execution they'd use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths` doesn't call delegate methods in all situation. It just simply deletes rows, If the rows being deleted are so many that they are occupying screen area, then it may call your delegate method. You have to explicitly call `reloadData` so that it refreshes its rows.

But calling `reloadData` immediately will spoil your animation or produce weird errors, since its rows are being deleted and you call reload method. *(It may go crazy)*. The alternate solution is to call `reloadData` after a slight delay like 0.2 or greater like this:

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2]; //calling reloadData after a short delay. 0.2 or whatever suits you.
```

Don't forget about deleting data from your datasource's array or whatever you are using to hold data.

Comment: in my case , rows being deleted are visible in the screen..still i can see it getting deleted with the animation , but it does not call its delegate or datasource methods. Is something wrong in my project or thats the way tableview does deletion. As it do make sense that tableview does not really need to call its datasource method   in case of deletion, just want to be sure if I can find it documented somewhere

Comment: No, nothing is wrong. Its the correct behavior. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/861250/593709) another related post.

Comment: Wouldn't a better solution be calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` inside the same `beginUpdates` block as the delete instead of messing with delay factors, etc?

Comment: @jszumski I guess animations are done in background (separate), we are unable to get the callback when this animation gonna end. that's why performing delayed selector is pretty straight forward. when using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, we need to calculate which paths? and (IMHO) both animation will be called on separate threads, thats why it may produce fuzzy output. what do you say?

Comment: All animations are always done on the main thread.  Getting the paths to load is easy, just use `tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows`.

Comment: that post does not  answer  my question. tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths will call datasource methods or not? if no then its fine but if yes then in what cases it wil call?

Comment: @iVishal: as I've already said in the post, that it'll call delegate methods in a case where it needs to show rows which are not visible in the tableView. if there are few rows which are already visible, it'll not call cellForIndexPath for those rows.

Comment: @jszumski but animation are not put in queue. they'll begin simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a question " why should it call all the datasource and delegate methods if the view is already popuated and all cells are readily available"?
well it **Should** be the behavior